# How to remove a string with varying numbers at the end

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to remove a string that begins with SRR and finishes by 'length = varying numbers with a varying length'. All I know about this number is that it varies between 1 and 200...

I do not know how to make it nor do I know what way would be the most efficient. I am manipulating large files (>10GB).

I wanted to do a loop for all values from 1 to 200 to be tested:

```
import os
import re
f2 = open(r'path')
num = 0
while num < 200:
    num = num+1
    ident2 = re.compile('SRR.*?%d' %num, re.DOTALL)
    stuff = f2.read()
    for line in f2:
        ident2.sub('',stuff)
```

The code is much longer overall, but yes I do write and close stuff up at the end. I am just wondering if I could use an expression that would take every number into consideration and remove the string...

Any suggestion, and constructive criticism will be greatly appreciated.

I am adding a sample of the text imput :

```
@SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50TTGCCTGCCTATCATTTTAGTGCCTGTGAGGTGGAGATGTGAGGATCAGT+SRR566546.970 HWUSI-EAS1673_11067_FC7070M:4:1:2299:1109 length=50hhhhhhhhhhghhghhhhhfhhhhhfffffe`ee[`X]b[d[ed`[Y[^Y
```

It is all one line and I have many repeats of similar sequences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just match digits:

```
re.compile('SRR.*?\d{1,3}', re.DOTALL)
```

`\d` matches the characters 0-9, `{1,3}` matches between 1 and 3 of them.

If you don't want to match anything that starts with `SRR` and then followed by a number higher than 200, you can create an expression that is more picky:

```
re.compile('SRR.*?(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|200)', re.DOTALL)
```

Matches a one-digit number between 1 and 9, *or* a 2 digit number between 10 and 99, *or* a 3 digit number between 100 and 199, *or* the number 200.

None of these expressions prevent the match from being followed by more digits. You may need to add the `\b` boundary anchor to the end of the expression:

```
re.compile('SRR.*?\d{1,3}\b', re.DOTALL)
```

For your posted sample, I'd explicitly include the `length=` parameter:

```
re.compile('SRR.*?length=(?:[1-9]|[1-9]\d|1\d{2}|200)', re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Wow, thanks I did not know that you could use the \d that way.

Comment: re.compile('^SRR.*?[012]{1,2}\d\b$', re.DOTALL)

Comment: @blackwind: which allows the pattern `000`, which is not a number at all. It disallows `199`, which *should* match.

Comment: re.compile('^SRR.*?[12]{0,2}[1-9]\b$', re.DOTALL)

@martin Thanks

Comment: You still don't allow for `199`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters Is regex the best method for large files?

Comment: @Fabien: processing the file as an iterator, line by line, is the best method for large files. If a regex is better than other options depends on what exactly you are trying to do; compare approaches with the `timeit` module.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters As for what I am actually trying to do. I am trying to take the sequence that stretches from SRR to length=number and delete it wherever it appears. I will try the timer. Thanks for everything.